# Program linking error without log message on intel driver

Tags: windows, visual-c++, opengl, glsl

Note: I will first spit out specifically my issue and then I will explain better my scenario.

On my windows, using my intel driver. I can compile these two (respectively vertex and fragment shader), but can not link them:

```
attribute vec4 vertex;
void main(void) {
       gl_Position = vertex;
}
```

*,*

```
uniform sampler2D textures[2];
vec4 third(sampler2D texture) {
       return texture2D(texture,vec2(0.5,0.5));
}
vec4 second(float a) {
       return third(textures[0]);
}

void main(void) {
       gl_FragColor = second(0.0);
}
```

I get an error on the linking (the link status is false) but the info log is empty.

The thing is that this shader works fine in my Linux with the same GPU and works fine in my NVIDIA. Only in windows using the Intel driver I get this problem. My OpenGL informs the following about the driver:

```
GL_VENDOR Intel
GL_RENDERER Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
GL_VERSION 3.0.0 - Build 8.15.10.2253
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION 1.30  - Intel Build 8.15.10.2253
```

Funny thing is that modifications that seems irrelevant makes the program to link correctly, I found a few so far:

1. If the second function does not receive any parameter, it works.
2. If main() calls third directly, it works.
3. If the uniform is not a array, it is a single element, it works.
4. If instead of passing the sampler2D from second to third, I pass an index that third will use to access textures, it works.

My question is how to make it work but keeping the same semantics? I need three functions, I needed that the `third` and the `main` function do not use the uniform, I need that only the `second` function knows the uniforms. Also, I need that the `second` and `third` function receives parameters. In my real world scenario the second and the third functions does a lot of things with the values it received.

And just for clarification, what I am doing that needs this:

In the framework that I am developing, there are three different fragment shaders being used. The first one (`main` in my reference code), is the one that the user provides, this one may call functions (`second` in my reference code) that are defined in the framework. The third level is also user provided but the shader is only compiled once and does not know how many times it will be used and it which values, the `second` is the responsible for allocating the right number of buffers and calling the `third` for each.

Here is the code that I used to test the shaders:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 640

void warn(const std::exception& e) {
#ifndef NDEBUG
    std::cerr << "Warning: " << e.what() << std::endl;
#endif
};

namespace {
std::string tostr(unsigned a) { 
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << a;
    return ss.str();
}

std::string errorname(unsigned a) {
    switch(a) {
    case GL_NO_ERROR:                      return "GL_NO_ERROR";
    case GL_INVALID_ENUM:                  return "GL_INVALID_ENUM";
    case GL_INVALID_VALUE:                 return "GL_INVALID_VALUE";
    case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:             return "GL_INVALID_OPERATION";
    case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: return "GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION";
    case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:                 return "GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY";
    }
    return "";
}

}

void checkGlErrorImpl(unsigned line, const char* file) {
    GLenum curerr = glGetError();
    if( curerr == GL_NO_ERROR )
        return;

    auto err = std::runtime_error(std::string("OpenGL ")+errorname(curerr)+" error on "+file+":"+tostr(line));
    warn(err);
    throw err;
}

#define checkGlError() checkGlErrorImpl(__LINE__,__FILE__)

int create_shader(unsigned type, const char* shaderSource) {
    unsigned id = glCreateShader(type);

    const char* shaderSources[2] = {"#version 130\n",shaderSource};
    glShaderSource(id,2,shaderSources,NULL);

    glCompileShader(id);
    GLint compileStatus;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileStatus);
        int msgLength;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &msgLength);

        char* msg = new char[msgLength];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, msgLength, &msgLength, msg);

        std::cout << "(" << id << ") " << msg << std::endl;

        std::runtime_error except(std::string("Error on compiling shader:\n")+msg);
        delete[] msg;
        if( compileStatus == GL_FALSE ) {
            warn(except);
            throw except;
        }

    checkGlError();

    return id;
};

int create_program(const std::vector<int>& shaders) {
    int id = glCreateProgram();
    checkGlError();
    for( unsigned int i=0; i< shaders.size(); ++i ) {
        glAttachShader(id,shaders[i]);
    }

    glLinkProgram(id);
    GLint linkStatus=-1;
    glGetProgramiv(id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);
    assert(linkStatus != -1);
    checkGlError();
    if( linkStatus == GL_FALSE ) {
        int msgLength=-1;
        glGetProgramiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &msgLength);
        assert( msgLength != -1 );

        char* msg = new char[msgLength+1];
        msg[0] = '\0';
        std::cout << "Buffer(" << msgLength+1 << ")" << msg << std::endl;
        glGetProgramInfoLog(id, msgLength+1, &msgLength, msg);
        std::cout << "Second length " << msgLength << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Log " << msg << std::endl;
        std::string errormsg("Error on linking shader: ");
        errormsg += msg;
//      delete[] msg;

        auto err = std::runtime_error(errormsg);
        warn(err);
        throw err;
    }

    checkGlError();

    return id;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 ) {
        throw __LINE__;
    }

    int video_flags;
    video_flags = SDL_OPENGL;
    video_flags |= SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    video_flags |= SDL_HWSURFACE;
    video_flags |= SDL_HWACCEL;
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_SetVideoMode( WIDTH, HEIGHT, 24, video_flags );
    if( surface == NULL )
        throw __LINE__;

    unsigned width = WIDTH;
    unsigned height = HEIGHT;

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
        throw __LINE__;
    }

    std::vector<int> shaders;
    shaders.push_back( create_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
        "attribute vec4 vertex;\n"
        "void main(void) {\n"
        "   gl_Position = vertex;\n"
        "}\n"
    ));
    shaders.push_back( create_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
        "uniform sampler2D textures[2];\n"
        "vec4 third(sampler2D texture) {\n"
        "   return texture2D(texture,vec2(0.5,0.5));\n"
        "}\n"
        "vec4 second(float a) {\n"
        "   return third(textures[0]);\n"
        "}\n"
        "\n"
        "void main(void) {\n"
        "   gl_FragColor = second(0.0);\n"
        "}\n"
    ));

    int program = create_program(shaders);

    try {
        while( true ) {
            SDL_Event event;
            while( SDL_PollEvent(&event) ) {
                switch( event.type ) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    throw 0;
                break;
                }
            }
            SDL_Delay(10);
        }
    } catch( int returnal) {
        return returnal;
    }
    return 0;
};
```

It depends on GLEW,SDL, OpenGL and C++11.

Comment: It was a bit hard to explain my problem and what I am trying to achieve, please comment if it is still not clear.

Comment: "*respectively geometry and fragment shader*" That's not a geometry shader. You can't use `attribute` in a geometry shader.

Comment: If you want OpenGL to work, without running into driver bugs, don't confuse the driver. Don't do things that are not in common usage, like linking multiple shaders for the same shader stage into the same program. It's just not a good idea.

Comment: @NicolBolas Even though my original problem appeared in multiple shaders, the code that I posted here uses only a single shader for each stage.

Comment: GL_VENDOR Intel
GL_RENDERER Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
GL_VERSION 3.0.0 - Build 8.15.10.2253
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION 1.30  - Intel Build 8.15.10.2253

Comment: Given the scenario and code provided, I'd try using the parameter in second(float), such as 'return third(textures[int(a)]);' Exception #1 "If the second function does not receive any parameter..." makes me think it's choking on a parameter that the compiler is optimizing out because it's unused.